# Display a shorcode below products in Woocommerce Storefront Category archives?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I need to add the following shortcode `[logoshowcase cat_id="427"]` in all product category pages, so it displays below of the product listed

I'm trying:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_my_text', 20 );
function add_my_text() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[logoshowcase cat_id="427"]' );
}
```

But it isn't working as I would like, specifically in product category archive pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but this hook works on last woocommerce version, but as storefront sidebar uses this hook too, you will need **to lower the hook priority under 10** if you want to display your shortcode below the products loop in archives and single product pages, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_my_text', 9 ); 
function add_my_text() {
    // Only on Woocommerce Category archive pages
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        echo do_shortcode( '[logoshowcase cat_id="427"]' ); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.